# How to get all the rows of datagridview and put them into textboxes

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to get all the rows of datagridview and put them into textboxes? 
 (There are only 6 rows ).

i want the rows to be placed into texboxes at the same time when they are loaded into datagridview without any select current row index or select multiple rows index .

Need Help!

Comment: Yes, you can loop the rows and concatenate it into the textbox.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen can u write the code ?

Comment: @Mib-af Yes, I can. But I can't help you if you don't show what you have done.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen just write the for-loop that takes the value of available rows from datagridview

Comment: The DataGridView has a property Rows. It's a collection of each row in the grid. That's what you should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following DataGridView has six columns defined in the IDE. There are three TextBoxes named TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3. The key on TextBoxes is to have a ordinal number so we can match up rows in the DataGridView to the TextBoxes. The other idea is to dynamically create TextBoxes but that brings in to play, real estate so that has too be considered in that case.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"A3", "B3", "C3", "D3", "E3", "F3"})


        Dim Data As String() = DataGridViewRowsToStringArray(DataGridView1)
        If Data.Count <= DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then
            Dim items As Control() = Nothing
            For row As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
                ' Find a TextBox as each textbox is named
                ' TextBoxn where n is a number e.g. TextBox1, TextBox2 etc.
                items = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & row + 1, False)
                If items IsNot Nothing Then
                    CType(items.FirstOrDefault, TextBox).Text = Data(row)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Function DataGridViewRowsToStringArray(ByVal sender As DataGridView) As String()

        Dim RowData =
            (
                From row In sender.Rows
                Where Not DirectCast(row, DataGridViewRow).IsNewRow
                Let RowItem = String.Join(",",
                    Array.ConvertAll(
                       (
                       From X In DirectCast(row, DataGridViewRow).Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray
                       ).ToArray,
                                          Function(c As DataGridViewCell) _
                                              If(c.Value Is Nothing, "", c.Value.ToString)))
                Select RowItem).ToArray

        Return RowData

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: can i ask a question ?

Comment: If the question is within the boundaries of the original question yet, if not best to start a new question.